# How to plot the equation for a semicircle

Tags: python, matplotlib, equation

My half circle doesn't really look like how I expected.

Am I doing this right or am I missing something pretty big here ?

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

coord_list = []


h = 0
k = 0
r = 6


for x in range((1 + h - r), (h + r - 1), 1):
    y1 = k + math.sqrt(r**2 - (x-h)**2)
    coord_list.append([x, y1])
   
    
for each in coord_list:
    print(each)

data = np.array([coord_list])

x, y = data.T

figure = plt.scatter(x, y)
figure = plt.grid(color = 'green', linestyle = '--', linewidth = 0.2)
figure = plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use `np.linspace` to create an array for the x values. Use many points to create the circle
- Use `np.sqrt` to solve for an array, instead of looping through each value.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# function for semicircle
def semicircle(r, h, k):
    x0 = h - r  # determine x start
    x1 = h + r  # determine x finish
    x = np.linspace(x0, x1, 10000)  # many points to solve for y

    # use numpy for array solving of the semicircle equation
    y = k + np.sqrt(r**2 - (x - h)**2)  
    return x, y


x, y = semicircle(6, 0, 0)  # function call
plt.scatter(x, y, s=3, c='turquoise')  # plot
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')  # set the plot aspect to be equal
```

[image]

Comment: How  can we change the direction 4 sides with formula? Now its North

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question.

Plotting the output of the code:

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

coord_list = []


h = 0
k = 0
r = 6


for x in range((1 + h - r), (h + r - 1), 1):
    y1 = k + math.sqrt(r**2 - (x-h)**2)
    coord_list.append([x, y1])
   
    
for each in coord_list:
    print(each)

data = np.array([coord_list])

x, y = data.T

figure = plt.scatter(x, y)
figure = plt.grid(color = 'green', linestyle = '--', linewidth = 0.2)
figure = plt.show()



[-5, 3.3166247903554]
[-4, 4.47213595499958]
[-3, 5.196152422706632]
[-2, 5.656854249492381]
[-1, 5.916079783099616]
[0, 6.0]
[1, 5.916079783099616]
[2, 5.656854249492381]
[3, 5.196152422706632]
[4, 4.47213595499958]
```

Looking at the output of the coordinates, it doesn't appear to be a circle.

[image]

But if we take our equation and our coordinates and graph them on this website we see that they are indeed a circle. It's an optical illusion that they aren't. Partially because the graph is not evenly displayed and also because plotting points in a range function with steps of 1 (line 13) doesn't plot points at equal arc length distances away from each other.

[image]